# Angular 16 Standalone component, "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'"

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

This is not the usual module-related. Because I'm using Angular v16, **standalone** component, no module is required.

TS

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-x',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],  // same err with or without  FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule
  templateUrl: './x.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./x.component.scss']
})
export class XComonponent
{
  public fg1?: FormGroup;
  // rest of the code
}
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="fg1">formGroup is highlighted as error</form>
```

This component is generated with `--standalone` switch in a legacy Angular project still using `@NgModule` in `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did to fix the issue was remove FormsModule, but keep ReactiveFormsModule in the imports of the @Component. Also adding a constructor to initializethe formgroup. Here is the [working stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-81nd6m?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts%3AL15&title=Angular%20Starter).

Here is the pasted code:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular 
    </a>
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup">form group example
  `,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  standalone: true,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      // your form controls go here
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Comment: seems `bootstrapApplication` is no need

Comment: Has no sense, you can import FormsModule also (really it's unnecesary, but you can). The solution is use some like `<form *ngIf="formGroup" [formGroup]="formGroup">` to avoid initials errors. @Jeb50, the `bootstrapApplication` makes that the Component "App" was who render at first

Answer (score 1):

Just import it in your imports section component

```
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common'
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core'
import { FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  templateUrl: './basic-page.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, JsonPipe],
})
export class BasicPageComponent {
  private fb = inject(FormBuilder)
  public myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [], []],
    price: [''],
    inStorage: [''],
  })
  // public myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  //   name: new FormControl(''),
  //   price: new FormControl(''),
  //   inStorage: new FormControl(''),
  // })
}
```

template:

```
<form autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="myForm">
 ...inputs    
 </form>
```

Comment: You can inject the formBuilder in constructor (really is the common way): `constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}` instead use `inject`

Comment: ¿Whats the difference? inject is a better way to do that

Answer (score 0):

In an application bootstrapped for standalone, you have to pull in the form providers with something like this:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        importProvidersFrom(FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule), ...]
```

If you aren't using standalone bootstrapping, I assume you still need to pull in the forms providers in your main NgModule.

Comment: I believe I was able to fix the issue without needing to do this. Refer to the stackblitz link in my answer!

Comment: seems `bootstrapApplication` is no need

Comment: **NO**, FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule should be import in `imports`, not as providers.